# Elasticsearch and Hive work together

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, bigdata

I see that Hive and Elasticsearch are almost equivalent except that Elasticsearch supports near real time queries. Moreover, Elasticsearch can run independently to store and analyze data. So why people use both Hive and Elasticsearch on Hadoop ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive and Elasticsearch are two really different tools.

Hive is a SQL to Hadoop Java translator to interact with virtually any datasource using SQL (including elasticsearch), using SerDe's. Hive can also store data using HDFS. Hive is really good at batch processing.

Elasticsearch is a distributed faceted search engine, it is very good to quickly retrieve data in millions of documents. It can also be used to make some simple calculations using facets.

Hive and ES are complementary, people use Hive to process data, and ES to deliver data / insights.

Comment: Could you give a specific use case that combining Hive and ES to enhance each other ?. I wonder that why don't we just use ES to retrieve data, big data ? Thank you.

Comment: Imagine a situation where data from multiple sources have to be joined (sales from an ERP, customers from a CRM). With Hadoop and Hive, I store the data, process it (join it), and send it to ES. With ES I create an application where I can sum all the sales by customers.

Comment: ES is very good to store and retrieve data, but is not able to join date from two differents "tables".

Comment: Could you give a brief description on how ES utilize Hadoop and MapReduce ,for example, to sum all the sales by customers ? btw, thanks alot for that useful answer.

Comment: ES doesn't use Hadoop to do any processing, ES is able to do many aggregations using facets and now [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) at query time.